# Fonts in table get messed up after sorting

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have a following problem I cant wrap my head around.

I have a report of open fault cases that is generated automatically and then send as HTML file to people that need to know.
Previously it was a simple table without any styles, text only. It wasn't very user friendly.
So I added styles and collapsing of cells if they're too long. 
Next I wanted to add sorting to it. I've found [simple example in JS from w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp) that works.

And here's the problem, when the report is open on mobile device in **Chrome** (also on desktop in **Responsive mode**) and the table is sorted, the font size will get messed up.
It affects only some columns and different ones depending on screen width.

This is how it looks like before sorting:
[image: before sorting]

And this is after:
[image: after sorting]

If you expand the cell, you could see that only text that wasn't hidden got messed up:
[image: expanded]

I tried enclosing the cells in additional DIVs and SPANs, trying different font-size attributes and adding width constraints. Nothing worked so far.
I'm not that proficient with HTML/CSS/JS to figure out what's wrong with it unfortunately.

I would be very glad for any help.

Here is an example report for you to try out:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  c = document.getElementsByClassName('expand');
  for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    lc = c[i].lastChild;
    lc.style.display = "none";
    lc.previousSibling.style.display = "inline";
  }
  c = document.getElementsByClassName('expand');
  for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    c[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      if (this.lastChild.style.display == "table") {
        this.lastChild.style.display = "none";
        this.lastChild.previousSibling.style.display = "initial"
      } else {
        this.lastChild.style.display = "table";
        this.lastChild.previousSibling.style.display = "none"
      }
      console.log(this.id, this.lastChild);
    })
  }
  h = document.getElementsByTagName("th");
  for (i = 0; i < h.length; i++) {
    h[i].innerHTML += "<br><span>&or; &and;</span>";
  }
}
sort_direction = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

function sortTable(column_id, direction) {
  // Method from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp
  direction = sort_direction[column_id];
  sort_direction[column_id] = sort_direction[column_id] * -1;
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
  table = document.getElementById("mainTable");
  switching = true;
  while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody");
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      shouldSwitch = false;
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[column_id];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("td")[column_id];
      if (direction == -1) {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (direction == 1) {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

th,
td,
.e {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  /* border-radius */
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* box-shadow */
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

th:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

tr {
  line-height: 14px;
}

table {
  border-style: none;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.expand {
  border: 1.5px solid DodgerBlue;
}

.expand:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.medium_cell {
  max-width: 220px;
}

.small_cell {
  max-width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<H1>Report</H1>
<h3>Report generated: 2018-06-05 13:10:07</h3>

<table id="mainTable" border="1" bordercolor="#C0C0C0" cellspasing="0" cellpadding="2">
<tbody><tr id="row0" class="class_row">
<th onclick="sortTable(0)">Case ID</th>
<th onclick="sortTable(1)">Status/Title</th>
<th onclick="sortTable(2)">Reported Date</th>
<th onclick="sortTable(3)">Notes</th>
<th onclick="sortTable(4)">Author</th>
<th onclick="sortTable(5)">Assigned Team</th>
<th onclick="sortTable(6)">Assigned Person</th>
<th onclick="sortTable(7)">Severity</th>
<th onclick="sortTable(8)">Priority</th>
<th onclick="sortTable(9)">Flags</th>
<th onclick="sortTable(10)">Information</th>
</tr></tbody>

<tbody><tr id="row3" class="class_row">  <td><a class="small_cell" href="#">ID654321</a></td>
  <td class="medium_cell"><p style="font-weight: bold">Many Many Many Lines Status</p>[TT18][TT00+6*TT18]Title of the reported fault</td>
  <td class="small_cell">23 May 2018</td>
  <td id="row3c1" class="expand medium_cell" style="font-size: 10px;"><div style="font-weight: bold">2018-05-00 00:00:00</div> xxxx xxxxxxxxx xx xxxxBxxx
x4 - xxxxxRxxx, xx. <p style="font-size: 4px;"/><div style="display:none; font-size: 12px;">&#8681; <span style="font-style: oblique; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold">click to expand</span> &#8681;</div><div style="display: table;"><div style="font-weight: bold">2018-05-00 00:00:00</div> xxxx xxxxRxx xx xxxxxxxxx
. xxxxxxx Rxxxxx xxxxxxxx.<BR><div style="font-weight: bold">2018-05-00 00:00:00</div> xxxx xxxxBxxx xx xxxxRxx
xxxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxx xxx</div></td>
  <td class="small_cell">Henry</td>
  <td>TEAMBLUE</td>
  <td class="small_cell">Maria</td>
  <td style="background-color:Orange; color:Black;">B<br>Major</td>
  <td style="background-color:Orange; color:Black;">2<br>Critical</td>
  <td></td>
  <td id="row3c2" class="expand"><span style="font-style: oblique">RC: unknown, LE: yyyy-mm-dd</span><div style="font-weight: bold">2018-05-00</div> xxxx (xxxxxx): xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxxxx; xR xxxx <p style="font-size: 4px;"/><div style="display:none; font-size: 12px;">&#8681; <span style="font-style: oblique; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold">click to expand</span> &#8681;</div><div style="display: table; margin: 0 auto;"><div style="font-weight: bold">2018-05-00</div> xxxx (xxxxxx): xxxxxxxxxxxxx</div></td>
</tr></tbody>


<tbody><tr id="row4" class="class_row">  <td><a class="small_cell" href="#">ID345678</a></td>
  <td class="medium_cell"><p style="font-weight: bold">Even Longer Status</p>[Title_tag][TT00]Title of the reported fault</td>
  <td class="small_cell">24 May 2018</td>
  <td class="medium_cell" id="row4c1" style="font-size: 10px;"><div style="font-weight: bold">2018-05-00 00:00:00</div> xxxx xxxxxxxxx xx xxxxBxxx
x4 - xxxxxRxxx, xx.</td>
  <td class="small_cell">Doug</td>
  <td>TEAMBLUE</td>
  <td class="small_cell">Ross</td>
  <td style="background-color:Orange; color:Black;">B<br>Major</td>
  <td style="background-color:Yellow; color:Black;">3<br>Normal</td>
  <td></td>
  <td id="row4c2" class="expand"><span style="font-style: oblique">RC: unknown, LE: yyyy-mm-dd</span><div style="font-weight: bold">2018-05-00</div> xxxxxx(xxxxxxxx): xxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxxx. <p style="font-size: 4px;"/><div style="display:none; font-size: 12px;">&#8681; <span style="font-style: oblique; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold">click to expand</span> &#8681;</div><div style="display: table; margin: 0 auto;"><div style="font-weight: bold">2018-05-00</div> xxxx (xxxxxx): xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxxxx; xR xxxx
<div style="font-weight: bold">2018-05-00</div> xxxx (xxxxxx): xxxxx xxxxx xx xx xxxxxxx xx xx xx345234</div></td>
</tr></tbody>
</table>
```

*** edit ***
If you want a file to download and try out yourself, you can get it [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1S2csawAtJHFVFqBy4b1HXJAT48Za6k_j)

Comment: I fixed your snippet. Please fix the error it gives

Comment: Well, I didn't really wanted to do this. I wanted to upload the code as is because it's automatically generated so I don't care that much about how pretty it is and formatting it messes up JS addressing with 'lastChild' and 'previousSibling'. But do you think that might be the cause of my problem?

Comment: I've replaced HTML part in a snippet with one that is not prettyfied. I'm sorry that it's less readable but it works.

Comment: Your code is *really* long and requires deep debugging. I suggest you try to isolate your question, by omitting parts of your algorithm and detecting what exactly causes your problem. If you still can't figure it out by yourself, attach **only** the relevant part of code and then we'll be able to help

Comment: I reduced the table to only two smallest rows. This is still enough to cause the problem. I tried to isolate it but my best guess is that it's somehow caused by window width. I don't get why would sorting that table caused fonts to change and only some of them. I've run out of ideas of what's wrong and where to look...